# How to cancel RadioButton or CheckBox checked change

Tags: .net, winforms, events

Is there any way to cancel a RadioButton or CheckBox's change in state before it changes?

I was hoping for a simple event like CheckedChanging or BeforeCheckedChange.

I really want to avoid listening for mouse clicks and key presses. But if you know of a proven reliable way of using mouse clicks and key presses, please explain it.

I'm using .NET 2.0 with standard Winforms controls.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set AutoCheck to false.

Override OnClick to manual check the checkbox

Comment: I never even knew AutoCheck existed. This is exactly what I want, thanks.

Comment: I wonder why this is different than some other controls where you would have something like a `CheckedChanging` event with an event argument where you could set `e.Cancel = true;` if you wanted to cancel the changing of the `Checked` property.

Comment: in case of radiobutton there is important note from doc: `If the AutoCheck property is set to false, a group of RadioButton controls will not act as a mutually exclusive group and the Checked property must be updated in code`

Answer (score 21):

Code demo's AutoCheck, adds a confirmation prompt to Click event.

> ```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
> {
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>         this.checkBox1.AutoCheck = false;
>         this.checkBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_Click);
>     }
>
>     private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
>         if (!checkBox.Checked)
>         {
>             DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
>                 "Are you sure?", "my caption",
>                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
>
>             if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
>             {
>                 checkBox.Checked = true;
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             checkBox.Checked = false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Does this work if space bar is pressed when the control has focus?

Comment: If I am the one who ask this question, I will definitely accept this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I used this to cancel a radio button check.

```
 private void radioButton1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)sender;
        r.Checked = !(r.Checked);
    }
```

Comment: The only problem I had with this approach is that the previous radio button has already been unchecked, so this doesn't completely undo the click. For that I had to add an event handler for the CheckedChanged event for each radio button, and when a radio button is unchecked, save which button was unchecked in case I need to check it again to completely undo the click.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cbSuspended_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Change status", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        cbSuspended.CheckedChanged -= cbSuspended_CheckedChanged;
        cbSuspended.Checked = !cbRemoved.Checked;
        cbSuspended.CheckedChanged += cbSuspended_CheckedChanged;
        return;
    }
}
```