# Changed checked state on checkbox with button appearance in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button, checkbox, appearance

As stated in my summary, I am currently working on a Virtual OS in VB.Net. I am currently working on the session as I am done with the login stuff.

I am having trouble with a checkbox with button appearance. I want to set the CheckState to Checked if I click on the button with the Click() event like this:

```
    Private Sub btnApps_Click(Byval sender As Object, Byval e As EventArgs) Handles btnApps.Click()
       If btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
          btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
       Else
          btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
       End If
    End Sub
```

I also tried the Checked property.

This code is not working at all, if I put the whole If-End If section in the CheckedChanged event I get a StackOverflowException. What am I doing wrong?

The CheckBox is a custom control b.t.w.

Comment: Try to cast sender to btnApps like: btnApps = e As ....

Comment: What is your gool with this code,because the button will stay Unchecked and there is no way to enter to the Else statement

Comment: i think that the normal behavior of Checkbox can do what you try to do with your code,so desactivate the code and try

Comment: I agree with @BeldiAnouar, if you do Debug.WriteLine(btnApps.CheckState) it will show Checked before the If statement, and then uncheck immediately when your code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to prevent your Checkbox from automatically changing state and change the appearance with your own Click event, you can turn AutoCheck to false.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.autocheck(v=vs.110).aspx

Information found thanks to this question: [How to cancel RadioButton or CheckBox checked change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371715/how-to-cancel-radiobutton-or-checkbox-checked-change)

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents btnApps As New clsChk

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    btnApps.AutoCheck = False
    Me.Controls.Add(btnApps)
End Sub

Private Sub btnApps_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApps.Click
    Debug.WriteLine(btnApps.CheckState)
    If btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    Else
        btnApps.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the answer I was looking for!