# How to prevent Checkbox Checkchanged event from firing in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my one function

```
If DataServices.IsGroupByMe(test) = True Then
            chkGroup.Visible = True
            chkGroup.Checked = True
        Else
            chkGroup.Checked = False
            chkGroup.Visible = False
        End If
```

Upon going through this line

```
chkGroup.Checked = True
```

It automatically calls my checkchanged event for that checkbox

```
 Private Sub chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkGroupOper.CheckedChanged
        LoadFilteredData()
    End Sub
```

Which then distrupts the usual sequence of action to perform. Are there ways to prevent triggering the checkchanged event?

**Please note that the first function in the base form. and the checkchanged event in a different child form inheriting the base.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel RadioButton or CheckBox checked change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371715/how-to-cancel-radiobutton-or-checkbox-checked-change)

Comment: Just add a Boolean field to your class, you could call it BypassDataLoad.  Now your event handler could be written as If Not BypassDataLoad Then LoadFilteredData()

Comment: How come your code refers to `chkGroup` but the event handler is bound to `chkGroupOper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use  a variable to block the update:

```
private bool PreventUpdate;

// your function
If DataServices.IsGroupByMe(test) = True Then
    PreventUpdate = true;
    // ... all tasks
   PreventUpdate = false;

// handler
Private Sub chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkGroupOper.CheckedChanged
    if not PreventUpdate Then
        LoadFilteredData()
    End Sub
```

Comment: will it work even if  that the first function in the base form. and the checkchanged event in a different child form inheriting the base.

Comment: then you should make it `protected` instead of `private`, so its accessible from all inherited classes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be to remove the Event Handler before settings its value and then re-assigning it.

Before setting the checked value (or at the start of the function):

```
RemoveHandler chkGroup.CheckedChanged, AddressOf chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged
```

And after setting the checked value (or at the end of the function):

```
AddHandler chkGroup.CheckedChanged, AddressOf chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged
```

Note: Anytime you add an EventHandler using the method above, always make sure there is a corresponding `RemoveHandler` called before it. Calling `RemoveHandler` too many times won't be a problem, but having your events handled too many times will cause you a few headaches wondering what is going on.

Comment: Please note that the first function in the base form. and the checkchanged event in a different child form inheriting the base.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer Then I think you need to decide if raising the `CheckChanged` event when calling the base function is appropriate. Personally, I am of the mind-set that the events for User Controls on a form should only be raised for User Actions, if they get raised as a side-effect (ie setting the value in code) then they should be disabled, like you are asking, and then re-enabled after they have been set.

Answer (score 1):

This is tough to answer since we don't really know the structure of your forms, in which form each piece of code reside nor how you interact with them.

However, one option is that you create a `Shared` property in the base form that indicates when `LoadFilterData()` should be bypassed.

Put this in your base form:

```
Protected Shared Property BypassDataLoad As Boolean = False
```

Then in your function do:

```
If DataServices.IsGroupByMe(test) = True Then
    BaseForm.BypassDataLoad = True
    chkGroup.Visible = True
    chkGroup.Checked = True
    BaseForm.BypassDataLoad = False
Else
    BaseForm.BypassDataLoad = True
    chkGroup.Checked = False
    chkGroup.Visible = False
    BaseForm.BypassDataLoad = False
End If
```

...and in your event handler:

```
Private Sub chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkGroupOper.CheckedChanged
    If Not BaseForm.BypassDataLoad Then
        LoadFilteredData()
    End If
End Sub
```

Replace `BaseForm` with the actual name of your base form class.

Comment: @Luke : I understand why you tried to edit (although you should've removed `Not` from the statement as well), however as the OP only has one line of code to execute I found this to be more readable than my intial `If Not BaseForm.BypassDataLoad Then LoadFilteredData()` (which isn't shown in the revisions since I removed it almost immediately). For longer code I do like you and use one line terminators: `If something = False Then Return`

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the event handler using [RemoveHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement) before setting the Checked property to true. Then in the else case where you set the Checked property to false you can add the eventhandler back using the [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement). so that whenever it is checked the actual event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Tag" property of the checkbox in order to control the "CheckChanged" event instead of removing and re-adding the handler again.
Please try the following code:

```
If DataServices.IsGroupByMe(test) Then
    chkGroup.Tag = "0"
    chkGroup.Visible = True
    chkGroup.Checked = True
Else
    chkGroup.Tag = "0"
    chkGroup.Checked = False
    chkGroup.Visible = False
End If



Private Sub chkGroupByMe_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkGroupOper.CheckedChanged
    If chkGroup.Tag <> "0" Then
        LoadFilteredData()
    End If
    chkGroup.Tag = ""
End Sub
```